# Check if a value is in range of 2 rows and print that row - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple dataframe like this :

```
import pandas as pd

input = 15
data = {
  "range": [0,10,20,30,40,50],
  "score": [50, 40, 45, 90, 20,48]
}

myvar = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I need to check in which range the variable input is within two rows and print that row. In this case, for example the output should be the second row (15 is in between 10 and 20). If I had input = 55 it should print the last row and so on.

What is the best solution using python ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
n = 15
myvar[myvar.range <= n].iloc[-1]
```

**output**

```
range    10
score    40
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

Note: I'm assuming the input (`n`) is always a non-negative number.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It actually works but when n is bigger than the last value of range it gives an error.

Comment: @GuilhermeAugusto I posted a new approach, check it out

Comment: It worked for my project. Thank you for your answer !

Comment: @GuilhermeAugusto nice! please consider vote and mark my answer as accepted if it was helpful :)